# Problems in rendering LaTeX for Inkscape 0.91 in Windows 7

Tags: inkscape

I find my Inkscape 0.91 for Windows 7 64-bit has problems in rendering
LaTeX. What I did was:

```
1) Extensions - Render - LaTeX
2) Enter "test" in LaTeX input
3) Click "Apply".
```

Then, a `cmd.exe` window will pop out and just hang there. If I close
this window, I get:

```
Inkscape has received additional data from the script executed. The
script did not return an error, but this may indicate the results will
not be as expected.

^Cinvalid LaTeX input:
test
temporary files were left in:
c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\inkscape-zxdypk
```

Could anyone please help? Thanks!

PS: `latex`, `dvips`, `gs`, and `pstoedit` are already in system path.

Shawn

---

Update on 2015-08-02:

I looked into the temporary files, and saw the eq.out file like this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `c:/users/admini'.
<to be read again>
                   \protect
<*> c:/users/admini~
                    1/appdata/local/temp/inkscape-wawis7/eq.tex
Please type another input file name:
```

Seems like a problem with Line 127 of the `eqtexsvg.py` file, that
Windows does not take this type of string as a valid file path.

Is that so? Is it non-trivial to fix it?

Shawn

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem and found some hack around it. It is not really a proper solution but it seems to work for me.

Looking at the errors and the structure of eqtexsvg.py it seems that the script wants to open a temporary directory, execute the LaTeX file in that directory, and then delete it again. It seems it somehow can't open the temporary folder in the "users" directory.

What I did to fix this was:

1. Open eqtexsvg.py (can be done with any text editor)
2. Change the line "base_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp("", "inkscape-");" into "base_dir = "<directory of your choice>"". I put in some directory on my documents hard drive.
3. Remove the line "os.rmdir(base_dir)"
4. Save the file again

That did it for me. It basically makes that eqtexsvg.py makes the temporary directory in some other location specified by you, where it can reach it. Note that the script automatically deletes the files it generates afterwards automatically. Removing the line (step 3) prevents it from removing the directory as well.

I don't claim this is a clean or nice solution, but at least it fixed the problem for me.